# Get the url parameter or the part of the url after the question mark (?) of an included php file

Tags: javascript, php, url

I basically have this "info.php" file included in another php file which is "main_page.php". By clicking a link in the page, the link sends a url parameter to the "info.php" file through javascript by reloading the page, giving it a new url. The "info.php" file then, for instance, becomes "info.php?student=1" which is, again, to be clear, included inside the "main_page.php" file. I've researched for solutions but what I only found are those javascripts and php scripts that gets the current url in the address bar.

Is there a way to do this, getting the new url of an included php file? If there is, then please forgive me for my dumbness and irresponsibly inadequate researching. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for.

```
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
```

Here is the **[documentation](https://www.php.net/reserved.variables.server.php)**

Comment: Or may be `PHP_SELF`. It's not very clear to me – what actually author wants to do.

Comment: OH GOD THIS REALLY IS! Thank you so much! Thank you!

Comment: @ShrinivasShukla By the way on the contrary, I can only access the result of the code only when it's inside the included php file which is the info.php. Is it possible to get this outside of the info.php file, in this case, in the main_page.php? I want to get the url of the included info.php file with the code inside main_page.php. Thanks if you still can help me :)

Comment: @carlomanangan, if `info.php?param1=value1` is the URL, then the query string will be obtained by the `test.php` as the parameters are passed to this file only.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access your URL query variables through the global [$_GET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) array.

```
$_GET['student']
```

> If not, please edit your question with some actual code like to have a better idea of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for this too, I know about this but I was focusing on trying to do this on javascript. I may actually consider this.

Comment: You are welcome. Note for next time that a short snippet of code usually helps to understand the nature of your question.